# Macro expansion with overloading

Tags: c++, macros

Is there some way to keep to use overloading with variable number of arguments?

Specific example is as follows:

```
// Third party class
class ABC
{
public:
    void addValue(int);
    void addValue(float);
    void addValue(string);
    void execute(); // Any number of add values can be called before the execute
};
```

Currently when I want to add values to the object of this class, I have to do as follows:
    ABC *obj = new ABC();
    obj->addValue(2.0); 
    obj->addValue("String"); 
    obj->execute();

Is there some way that in the client code I can do all the addValues in 1 line?

I tried using macros as follow, but then I have to define a macro for every number of arguments:

```
#define ADD_1_VALUES_TO_CLASS_ABC(obj, val1) { \
    obj->addValue(val1) }
#define ADD_2_VALUES_TO_CLASS_ABC(obj, val1, val2) { \
    obj->addValue(val1); obj->addValue(val2) }
#define ADD_3_VALUES_TO_CLASS_ABC(obj, val1, val2, val3) { \
    obj->addValue(val1) ; obj->addValue(val2); obj->addValue(val3) }
```

Is there some generic way to define MACRO ADD_N_VALUES_TO_CLASS_ABC and call it like

```
ABC *obj = new ABC();
MACRO ADD_N_VALUES_TO_CLASS_ABC(obj, "String", 1.0, 4);
MACRO ADD_N_VALUES_TO_CLASS_ABC(obj, 1, 2.0, "String", 4.0, 3);
```

Also if I use variable number of arguments va_args, I lose the type information needed to call the overloaded function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you work with a C++11 compiler?

Comment: have a look at boost.pp or maybe even calling it as ABC((p1,p2,p3)) is enough for you.

Comment: *Variadic* is the keyword here. Be it variadic templates or variadic macros (the latter probably being simpler). Alternatively a minor refactor might help: `ABC& add(int);` and then use as `obj->add(5).add("String").add(1.0)` becomes slightly less cumbersome to write.

Comment: Compiler is g++ version 4.1.2 on Linux. 
The ABC class is 3rd party and cannot be modified.

Answer (score 2):

On a compliant C++11 compiler, you can use variadic templates to achieve that:

```
template<typename T>
void addValues(ABC& obj, T&& t)
{
    obj.addValue(forward<T>(t));
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void addValues(ABC& obj, T&& t, Ts&&... ts)
{
    obj.addValue(forward<T>(t));
    addValues(obj, forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

This is how you would use it:

```
ABC a;
add_values(a, 3, "hello", 4.5f);
```

Comment: wears his robe and a wizard hat

Comment: Your answer really helped me root out silly issues with my own, so kudos for getting it right from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Using the C++11 feature called variadic templates (available in GCC from version 4.3) you can add the following member function:

```
void addValues(){}; // Base case.

template<class H, class... T>
void addValues(H&& head, T&&... tail)
{
    addValue(std::forward<H>(head));
    addValues(std::forward<T>(tail)...);
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
addValues(1, 2.0, "String", 4.0, 3);
```

is equivalent to

```
addValue(1); addValue(2.0); addValue("String"); addValue(4.0); addValue(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you are using g++ version 4.1.2 (which is fairly old), apparently C++11 is not an option.  Fortunately, you don't need it!  It is possible to use variadic macros, but a much simpler and more elegant C++ solution is to think like cout, and do:

```
class AddTo {
  ABC *abc;
  public:
  AddTo(ABC *abc) : abc(abc) { }
  template<class T>
  const AddTo& operator<<(const T& val) const {
    abc->addValue(val);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Then you can use this like:

```
ABC *obj = new ABC();
AddTo(obj) << 1 << 2.0 << "String" << 4.0 << 3;
```